# Find strings with StartsWith and EndsWithChar

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the whole text in a string called "Str"

I need to find any string like this (it can be a whole line or one word)

*text*

Can I possibly do this using Regex or split ? Need a bit of help understanding this.

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you're asking. Please give a full example, ideally with a [mcve] of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below :

```
Dim startIndex, endIndex As Integer
mystring = "Hello there, I'm [Here] to answer all the [questions that you can ask] Can I return two [strings] only from this string Here and questions that you can ask"
While mystring.Contains("[") Or mystring.Contains("]")
    startIndex = mystring.IndexOf("[") + 1
    endIndex = mystring.IndexOf("]") - startIndex
    MessageBox.Show(mystring.Substring(startIndex, endIndex))
    mystring = mystring.Substring(mystring.IndexOf("]") + 1)
End While
```

Comment: I think my question is mistaken. 

I want to know that how can I find any string that starts and ends with particular character. is that possible ?

Comment: Off course. Please give some example of string and expected result. The more you provide detail, the more exact answer you will get.

Comment: Str = "Hello there, I'm [Here] to answer all the [questions that you can ask]"

Can I return two strings only from this string
"Here" and
"questions that you can ask"

Comment: You mean the strings to return which are start with `[` ans ends with `]` ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer now and also modify your question and add the clarification you wrote here.